# printf in a function repeatedly prints, then stops and works correctly

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on a blackjack program in C, just because, and I'm stuck on strange bug.

This is the code (sorry for all the commented lines, I'm trying to track down this bug):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    #define NUM_SUITS 4
    #define NUM_RANKS 13

    void deal(int *pnum_cards, int *prank) {  

      static bool in_hand[NUM_SUITS][NUM_RANKS] = {false}; 
      const char rank_code[] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K',};        

    int suit = 0, rank = 0;

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL)); 
    suit = rand() % NUM_SUITS;
        rank = rand() % NUM_RANKS; 


    if (!in_hand[suit][rank]) {
        in_hand[suit][rank] = true;
        *pnum_cards = *pnum_cards - 1;
    printf("Pnum_cards In deal %d\n", *pnum_cards);
        if (suit == 0){
            printf("%c of Clubs \n", rank_code[rank]);
            }
        else if (suit == 1){
            printf("%c of Diamonds \n", rank_code[rank]);
        }
        else if (suit == 2){
            printf("%c of Hearts \n", rank_code[rank]);
        }
        else if (suit == 3){
            printf("%c of Spades \n", rank_code[rank]);
        }
    }
//  return rank;
//  printf("Rank In deal %d\n", rank);
    *prank = rank+1;
    printf("prank in deal %d\n", *prank);

}

}

int main() {

    int t, newcard;

    int stay = {false};
    int f;

    int rank = 0,  *prank = &rank;
    int totrank = 0, *ptotrank = &totrank;
    int num_cards = 2, *pnum_cards = &num_cards;
        printf("Prima del while %d\n", *pnum_cards);        

    printf("Your hand: ");

    while (*pnum_cards > 0) {
        deal(&num_cards, &rank);
//      printf("Nel while: %d\n", *pnum_cards);
//totrank_check(&totrank, &rank);
    }

    printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Technically it works. The problem is, and I can't figure out why, that when it gets to

```
    printf("prank in deal %d\n", *prank);
```

Which is the last printf in function deal() it does something strenge in the first while cycle, it prints that phrase like for a thousand times, then it suddenly stops, it exits the function, executes the second cycles, calls the function again, prints everything it has to, gets to the last printf, it prints it once and it stops, just as intended.

So I don't think it's a problem with the while-loop, because it basically works, it just gets stuck on that printf for a while. What could it be?

Comment: @YuHao, you're right, sorry!

Comment: @user3121023: That's already the solution. Please consider posting this as an answer. (While the same seed is used, i.e. while the time value is the same, the same card will get generated.)

Comment: @user3121023 I can't believe that worked. But why is that? Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @MOehm That wasn't the problem though (I think). It was only printing the same value over and over, but it stopped at a certain point (not sure why) and the it worked as intended.

Comment: The idea is to seed the pseudo-random generator only once. You seeded it before each card. `time` returns the number of seconds after a certain date, the epoch. You generate the same number over and over until the system clock advanced one second. Because you only draw two cards, the second pick will succeed. If you draw ten cards, you'll get a lot of output and ten cards after nine seconds. But user3121023 has already axplained that in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time ( NULL)` returns the number of seconds.
for one second `srand ( time ( NULL))` will get identical seed.
for identical seed, rand will generate the same list of random numbers.
Move `srand ( time ( NULL))` to main so it only gets called once instead of each time the deal function is called.